# Android Canvas Performance Very Inconsistent Versus Other Devices

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas

I've been working on a simple endless runner android game in 2D. I've opted to go with the canvas route as the learning curve for Open GL seems to be relatively high. I've been following this tutorial so far:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/tutorials/android-tutorials/android-game-tutorials/

And with the game loop exactly the same:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-game-loop.html

My problem is my game is running at a good 60 FPS on my Galaxy Nexus but when I put the game onto my girlfriend's Nexus 4, the FPS drops to 40 and game performance is very choppy. Same with my cousin's Galaxy S2.

I'm currently using:

MainGamePanel.java

```
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

I've heard RGB_565 gives better performance, but this actually drops my FPS on my device down to 40 and FPS is same with other devices

Have hardware acceleration enabled, doesn't seem to do much though:

AndroidManifest

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

In my MainGamePanel, I instantiate all objects that will be drawn onto the canvas before the thread is started:

```
public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    initScreenMetrics(context);
    initGameMetrics();

    BitmapOptions options = new BitmapOptions();
    drillBit = new Drill(getResources(), 0);
    drillBit.setX((screenWidth - drillBit.getBitmap().getWidth()) / 2);
    drillBackground = new DrillBackground(getResources(), drillBit.getX(), drillBit.getY());
    diamond = new Interactable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.diamond, options.getOptions()), screenWidth/2, screenHeight+30);
    potion = new Interactable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.potion, options.getOptions()), screenWidth/4, screenHeight+230);
    oil = new Interactable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.oil_1, options.getOptions()), 3*screenWidth/4, screenHeight+450);
    powerUp = new Interactable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.power_up, options.getOptions()), 
            3*screenWidth/4, screenHeight+130);

    background = new Background(getResources());

    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);
}
```

To animate the drillBit object, I have 4 bitmaps in the constructor and each time the game loops, I switch off the bitmaps (can't think of another way to accomplish this):

drill.java

```
public Drill(Resources resource, int x) {
    BitmapOptions options = new BitmapOptions();
    bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resource, R.drawable.drill_1, options.getOptions());
    bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resource, R.drawable.drill_2, options.getOptions());
    bitmap3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resource, R.drawable.drill_3, options.getOptions());
    bitmap4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resource, R.drawable.drill_4, options.getOptions());
    currentBitmap = bitmap1;
//other stuff
}
```

draw function in drill:

```
        if (currentBitmap == bitmap1) {
        currentBitmap = bitmap2;
    }
    else if (currentBitmap == bitmap2) {
        currentBitmap = bitmap3;
    }
    else if (currentBitmap == bitmap3) {
        currentBitmap = bitmap4;
    }
    else {
        currentBitmap = bitmap1;
    }
    canvas.draw(currentbitmap, x, y, null);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because Canvas draws everything based on pixel.Pixel is different in different resolution devices. So when you execute (screenHeight+30) will draw different in different device. So you can not write directly +30, you need to convert 30 in device dependent pixel.

I use this method to convert static values

```
public int convertSizeToDeviceDependent(int value,Context mContext) {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) mContext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        return ((dm.densityDpi * value) / 160);
    }
```

**Where to use**

```
diamond = new Interactable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.diamond, options.getOptions()), screenWidth/2, screenHeight+convertSizeToDeviceDependent(30,context));
```

**apply this method to all places where you using hard coded values in this lines**

```
diamond = new Interactable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.diamond, options.getOptions()), screenWidth/2, screenHeight+30);
    potion = new Interactable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.potion, options.getOptions()), screenWidth/4, screenHeight+230);
    oil = new Interactable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.oil_1, options.getOptions()), 3*screenWidth/4, screenHeight+450);
    powerUp = new Interactable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.power_up, options.getOptions()), 
            3*screenWidth/4, screenHeight+130);
```

Comment: I've added this function to any place I could find that has pixel values and I got about 5 fps more, but the nexus 4 is still comparably slower than my galaxy nexus. Any other ideas?